# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' on macOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Tkinter doesn't work, it throws an error.

Installation:

```
% pip3 install tk
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arghadip/Library/Application Support/CodeRunner/Unsaved/Untitled.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Comment: ```_tkinter```, so your python might not be configured for ```tkinter```

Comment: how do I configure it?

Comment: ```brew install python-tk``` try

Comment: It worked, but can you tell me what is ```pip3 install tk``` then?

Comment: @user15242190 tk is tensorkit on pypi, not tkinter. https://pypi.org/project/tk/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For Python3 tkinter can be simply installed by,

```
brew install python-tk
```

pip sometimes wont work successfully on my Mac, especially with the High Sierra OS version. Brew can be used to install all kinds of software packages in mac.

Comment: It worked for me. a point to note is: I'm using python 3.10 so I have to specify version when install tk like `brew install python-tk@3.10` otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, Richard! It worked for me with the version.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with the module name change in Python2 to Python3.. as stated in the previous post, "brew install python-tk" worked for me. I'm running the following:

- Python 3.9.13 64-bit
- vsCode 1.68.0
- macOS Monterey

Answer (score 0):

If you are in macOS, you can run the below commands to install `python-tk`. I have tested it on the latest macOS Ventura 13.1 and it worked like a charm.

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man8`
`chmod u+w /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man8`

`brew install python-tk`