# Try to get variable type on python3 on macOS and it show the below error

Tags: macos-catalina, python-3.9

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/kane/study/python/basicDataStructure/liner_data_structure.py", line 2, in <module> from turtle import clear File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 107, in <module> import tkinter as TK File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module> import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`

**Note** Please note that, I didn't use anything regarding tkinter. I only created a variable and checked its type.

I have found the answer at the link
[brew install python-tk](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554782/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tkinter-on-macos)

Comment: Are you sure that the file path is correct?

Comment: Please note that I did use anything regarding Tkinter or any library else. 
I have tried to get variable type on python2 and it's OK.
When I have tried to get variable type on python3 and it shown the bugs.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to firstly import it on the os device!
Run these in your terminal

python3 get-pip.py

Pip install turtle
Pip install tkinter

Comment: I only created a variable and checked its type. I did use anything regarding Tkinter, or anything else.
I have checked on python2 and it shows variable type when trying python3 its shows bug

Comment: You can't install tkinter with pip.

Comment: You can for sure