# How to install tkinter on M1 Mac

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to run app with Mac M1

Errors are:

```
bash-3.2$ brew install tkinter
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 8 formulae.

Warning: No available formula with the name "tkinter".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

bash-3.2$ pip install tkinter
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

Comment: Do you already have python installed? Tkinter is usually part of a standard python distribution. Unfortunately I don't have an m1 mac to try it out.

Comment: Yes. Frustrating because I want to play.

Comment: You have python installed? What happens when you try to import tkinter?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-29b37e014535> in <module>
----> 1 import tkinter

/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py in <module>
     35 import types
     36 
---> 37 import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
     38 TclError = _tkinter.TclError
     39 from tkinter.constants import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68554984/7432

Answer (score 4):

Apparently on MacOS' python, `tkinter` is not a built-in and can't be installed with `pip`. In order to install it you need either **[MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php)** or **[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)**. Since the newest `tkinter` module for python 3.11 is still a little bit buggy, I would recommend you to install the tkinter module for python 3.9 which is more stable by running either of these commands:

- With **MacPorts**

```bash
sudo port install py39-tkinter
```

- With **Homebrew**

```bash
brew install python-tk@3.9
```

but if you insist on installing the latest version, go ahead with either of these:

```bash
sudo port install py311-tkinter
```

```bash
brew install python-tk
```

After installing, you should instantly be able to `import tkinter`.