# vs code no module named "_tkinter" found

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I was working on a Python project when I had to restart my vscode. After relaunching it for some reason none of my modules won't load and I keep getting the error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named '_tkinter'
  File "...", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

And all of my other imported modules appear with the orange error underscore.

I made sure to check that the modules were installed and it kept telling me that they are:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pydub in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

And I restarted vscode and even reinstalled it but nothing worked.

Comment: Not sure though what having `pydub` installed has to do with importing `tkinter`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\_tkinter' on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554782/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tkinter-on-macos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure the modules are already installed, maybe check whether you're using the right interpreter. Around the top right, there should be a button saying something like "(Python 3.x.x)", click on that and change the interpreter there and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> Python: Select Interpreter --> **Choose the correct interpreter**

  [image]
- The current interpreter version will be displayed in the lower right corner of the vscode interface.

  [image]
- Make sure to execute the script with the **Python** extension

  [image]